# how to sign request tokens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, jwt

I am currently trying to write a script to send off a request token, I have the header, and the claimset, but I don't understand the signature! OAuth requires my private key to be encrypted with SHA256withRSA (also known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function), but the closest I could find was RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 (has RSA, and the SHA-256 hash). I followed the example, and tweaked it, so I could get it set, but heres my dillema:
    signature = ""
    h = SHA.new (signature)

```
key = RSA.importKey(open('C:\Users\Documents\Library\KEY\My Project 905320c6324f.json').read())
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(message+h.digest())
print(ciphertext)
```

I'm a bit lost, the JSON file I was given has both public key, and private, do I copy and paste the private key into the signature variable (it gave me a invalid syntax)? Or do I past the directory again? I am so lost, and way over my head haha. I am currently running Python 3.4, with pyCrypto for the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've said below about wanting to write a command system using gmail, I wrote a simple script to do this using IMAP. I think this is probably simpler than trying to use Google APIs for a single user, unless you were wanting to do that simply for the exercise.

```
import imaplib, logging
from time import sleep

USERNAME = 'YOUR_USERNAME_HERE' # For gmail, this is your full email address.
PASSWORD = 'YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE'
CHECK_DELAY = 60 # In seconds

LOGGING_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename='imapTest.log', format=LOGGING_FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)

logging.info("Connecting to IMAP server...")
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
imap.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
logging.info("Connected to IMAP server.")

def get_command_messages():
    logging.info("Checking for new commands.")
    imap.check()
    # Search the inbox (server-side) for messages containing the subject 'COMMAND' and which are from you.
    # Substitute USERNAME below for the sending email address if it differs.
    typ, data = imap.search(None, '(FROM "%s" SUBJECT "COMMAND")' %(USERNAME))
    return data[0]

def delete_messages(message_nums):
    logging.info("Deleting old commands.")
    for message in message_nums.split():
        imap.store(message, '+FLAGS', '\\DELETED')
    imap.expunge()

# Select the inbox
imap.select()

# Delete any messages left over that match commands, so we are starting 'clean'.
# This probably isn't the nicest way to do this, but saves checking the DATE header.
message_nums = get_command_messages()
delete_messages(message_nums)

try:
    while True:
        sleep(CHECK_DELAY)
        # Get the message body and sent time. Use BODY.PEEK instead of BODY if you don't want to mark the message as read, but we're deleting it anyway below.
        message_nums = get_command_messages()
        if message_nums:
            # search returns space-separated message IDs, but we need them comma-separated for fetch.
            typ, messages = imap.fetch(message_nums.replace(' ', ','), '(BODY[TEXT])')
            logging.info("Found %d commands" %(len(messages[0])))
            for message in messages[0]:
                # You now have the message body in the message variable.
                # From here, you can check against it to perform commands, e.g:
                if 'shutdown' in message:
                    print("I got a shutdown command!")
                    # Do stuff
            delete_messages(message_nums)
finally:
    try:
        imap.close()
    except:
        pass
    imap.logout()
```

If you're set on using the Gmail API, though, Google strongly encourage you to use their existing Python library rather than attempt to do full authentication etc. yourself as you appear to be. With that, it should - more or less - be a case of replacing the imap calls above with the relevant Gmail API ones.

Comment: I'm going off what it says on the google developer site, it doesn't provide much info other than it needs to be signed with RSASHA256. Do you have a link to the explanation?

Comment: Would [Google's Python library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) be of any use to you, then? If so, that page explains how to use it, as well as providing a link to download only the oauth client if that's all you need. In particular, I suspect the `flow_from_clientsecrets()` method would be what you're needing. Beyond that, I'm not sure I can help without knowing what you're wanting to do with a specific Google API.

Comment: I set up a service account, and with the Gmail API I was planning on using it to bridge my pc and phone via texing (email), with that I was hoping to send commands with a text like "command: reboot". It's more or less a script to help me with interacting with api's and bigger projects. My problem is still with the token request, because I need to sign my own JWT.

Comment: Okay, so going through the process myself - it seems that what you need to create is an Application type: Installed application (and then  select 'Other' type within that). That then gives you the correct `client_secret.json` file to work with. From there, I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python), and had to also install `python-gflags` and add an `Email Address` and `Product Name` to the consent screen on the Google developers console. Following this, their quickstart code worked.

Comment: Once you have that working, it should be fairly easy to follow the api docs to get a list of messages and then scan a particular message for your required keywords. Have you considered that accessing your inbox via IMAP might be an easier way to do this, though? Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding what you're attempting to achieve - perhaps you are intentionally doing it this way as an exercise.

Comment: I have changed my answer to implement what (I think) you're trying to achieve, but using IMAP instead of Google APIs. I hope that's acceptable for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)! I didn't even think of using IMAP haha (I knew it was there it just totally slipt my mind haha). You were really helpful, and I really appreciate that!

Comment: Yeah, I think it's probably 'more useful' in the general case, since obviously it can be used for other email providers too. Does that answer your question such that this can be the accepted answer, or are you still looking for an answer to your original token signing question?

Comment: sorry haha, didn't realize I had to mark it as the accepted answer :), thank you once again.